# For RF, if two relays specify 60W max power, but one is 2A and the other is 5A, does current matter?

Tags: power, current, rf, switches, relay

This [TE RF relay](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/418/ENG_SS_108-98001_S%5B1%5D-1210543.pdf) comes in 2A and 5A varieties depending on the model number.

In both cases the max power is 60W (62.5VA).

**Is there any reason to go with the 5A model since the 2A model is also power-limited to 60W?**

Relatedly, it has high-dielectric and high-stability varieties.  Would either of those be better for RF?  If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the different current ratings is that the 2 A versions use palladium/ruthenium alloy contacts, while the 5 A version uses silver/nickel contacts. Silver has lower resistance than palladium and ruthenium so it can pass more current without overheating. Another reason to use silver at higher current is that palladium attracts organic vapors which might be outgassed from the plastic parts if they get hot, forming an insulating film on the contacts.

However silver suffers more from erosion when arcing, so the power rating is not increased. Erosion also reduces contact stability, so if you need the most stable contact and don't need more than 2 A then palladium/ruthenium may be better. On the other hand if you are switching very low voltage then silver/nickel may be better.

So which relay is 'best' depends on the particular application. RF relays are typically used to switch an antenna from transmit to receive, where they have to work well at both high and very low power. Transmit current and voltage depend on the transmit power level and impedance. The receive contacts may need a [wetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetting_current) current applied to make the connection reliable, and palladium will probably need more than silver.

I'm guessing 'high-dielectric' means high dielectric *strength*, ie. the ability to withstand higher surge voltages (thus why it says "surge capability **up to** 2500Vrms between open contacts and 3000Vrms between coil and contacts").

Comment: This is an RF front-end, so the RX voltages will be tiny.  Silver sounds like the best option!

Answer (score 1):

It's a signal relay datasheet with additional data for RF applications.

Signal relays are small mechanical relays with voltage and current ratings intended for switching low-power control and measurement signals.

Their DC and AC switching ratings are as follows:

- DC switching: Current 2 A, voltage 220 V and power 60 W.
- AC switching: Current 5 A, voltage 250 V and power 62.5 VA.